# lazy loading a uicollectionview cause app crash when collectionview dequeues a reusable cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

my `HomeHorizontalSpecialCell` inherited UICollectionViewCell, and has a property which is collectionView. And this collectionView constructs by lazy loading

```
private lazy var _collectionView: UICollectionView! = {
   let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
   layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
   layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
   let itemWidth = (kScreenWidth - 4 * layout.minimumLineSpacing) / 3.4
   let itemHeight = itemWidth
   layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
   let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: kScreenWidth, height: itemHeight), collectionViewLayout: layout)
   collectionView.delegate = self
   collectionView.dataSource = self
   collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
   collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7)
   // register cell
   collectionView.register(HomeHorizontalSpecialGoodCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HomeHorizontalSpecialCell.reuseSpecialCellID)
   collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
   self.contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
   return collectionView
    }()
```

when set data, this collectionView calls to `reloadData` method and begin to construct and register cell.
    in dataSource methods, I dequeue these registered reusable cells

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   // crash at here on big size iPhone
   let specialGoodCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HomeHorizontalSpecialCell.reuseSpecialCellID, for: indexPath) as! HomeHorizontalSpecialGoodCell
   if indexPath.row != (_dataList?._item.count)! { // good cells
       specialGoodCell.goodModel = _dataList?._item[indexPath.row]
   } else { // last cell
       specialGoodCell.setMoreImage("spe_more")
   }
   return specialGoodCell
}
```

force to unwrap a cell cause App crash when collectionView dequeue a cell on some big size iPhones, but small size not.
i found the situation where directly initial `HomeHorizontalSpecialCell` at first time at big size iPhone, but at small size it need to scroll collectionView to initial this cell instance.

why does app crash when loading this cell at big size iPhone?

someone can help?

Comment: Please put in the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is using the viewController as the datasource and delegate of the collectionView. Maybe this article can help you.
[Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell in Swift](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/)